# Developing Visual Studio C++ projects in a Linux environment

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

I'm about to begin a new consulting position that involves refactoring a **ton** of Visual Studio 2010 C++ code. I have used Visual Studio for very basic projects before, but I prefer developing in a Ubuntu or Mac OS environment.

Are there any proprietary "components" of Visual Studio 2010-2017 projects that would prevent me from developing code in say Ubuntu... and then testing in Windows through Visual Studio?

The only thing that comes to mind is Microsoft C++ libraries that are not readily available to Ubuntu or Mac.

Are there any major compiler differences between g++ and the Visual C++ compiler?

Comment: How come that *refactoring* requires platform switch all of it sudden? Anyway your question seems to be rather broad.

Comment: The refactoring doesn't require a platform switch, it's just my preference for development. To be more specific... I want to develop the project in a UNIX environment and then test in Visual Studio X.

Comment: It depends on the project. It's very easy to come to rely on Windows-specific libraries when you develop using VS. If the project is not meant to be cross-platform and uses Windows-specific libraries all over the place, you will be hard pressed to work on it in Ubuntu. I am not sure about Mac OS. I've never developed on that platform.

Comment: [Completely off topic] @VTT are you really from Antarctica.... Your profile location pins to it.

Comment: [Completely off topic] @katamarayudu Just got stuck in the ICE for a while, but global warning caused it to melt and now I'm surrounded by penguins.

Comment: @RSahu is it possible to build Visual C++ libraries in a Linux environment?

Comment: The current version of g++ supports more modern features of C++ than VC. But how exactly do you expect to build code that references MS-Windows library, MS-Windows header files, and other MS-Resources on native Ubuntu?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so that's essentially the question I'm getting to... is it possible to build code that references Visual C++ libraries in a Linux environment?

Comment: @KendallWeihe, only if you are the developer of the library and it does not have any dependencies on Windows-specific libraries.

Comment: There short answer is: nope. You do realize that even the binary format used on Linux is completely different, and has absolutely nothing in common, whatsoever, with the `.exe`s and `.dll`s on MS-Windows, so even if you meticulously copy over all the header files, good luck trying to link the code.

Comment: We need some more details. The C++ code for Windows that you're supposed to refactor, for example, does it involve COM? (you would be surprised) Does it use header files for Windows? Does it use low level Windows APIs? However, I would say that in general it is better to develop for Windows in a Windows machine. You could do something like develop in Ubuntu and then move everything into a Windows machine to test, but it would save you a lot of time to just do it straight in a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference between VS's compiler and GCC. And most fully fledged ides can open VS solution files. So you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to use cmake, you can test core routine in linux.

and back to visual studio sln through cmake build system.